# Difference between classifier and estimator

Tags: naive-bayes, scikit-learn

Reading documentation of Naive Bayes from sklearn, I read the following:

"On the flip side, although naive Bayes is known as a decent classifier, it is known to be a bad estimator, so the probability outputs from predict_proba are not to be taken too seriously."

What that does mean?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like it means that naive Bayes usually gets right whether the probability is > 0.5 or < 0.5 (or whatever cutoff you are using for classification) but often gets it far from correct within those ranges.

That seems odd to me, but I know little about naive Bayes.